# Unix command status is different for same parameter and same command

Tags: shell

Below is the set of command I tried consecutively. but $? returns different values each time,

```
:~/workspace/bitbucket_copy/linuximage$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libcurl-dev
Package libcurl-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl-dev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl-dev' found

:~/workspace/bitbucket_copy/linuximage$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libcurl-dev | echo $?
1
Package libcurl-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl-dev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl-dev' found

:~/workspace/bitbucket_copy/linuximage$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libcurl-dev | echo $?
0
Package libcurl-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl-dev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl-dev' found
```

Comment: To get an accurate reading on the exit status, don't pipe: wait until the command has exited -> `pkg-config ... ; echo $?`

Comment: I have enabled "set -e" on my shell script does it still work ?

Comment: No. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 and the pages it links to.